# RXJs Service to return multiple observables

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the following searchService.search method that returns a forkJoin of two api calls.

I want the calls to execute simultaneously which they are but I also want each response back as a single object that can be passed into my SearchSuccess action and processed immediately without waiting for all calls to complete.  Currently they are returning as an array of responses and only upon completion of both API calls - as this is what forkJoin is used for.

My issue is that I'm struggling to find another operator that does what I want.

Or perhaps the code pattern requires some redesign?

action:

```typescript
@Effect()
trySearch: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SearchActionTypes.TrySearch),
  switchMap((action: TrySearch) =>
    this.searchService.search(action.payload)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => new SearchSuccess(data)),
          catchError(error => of(new SearchFail(error))),
        ),
  ),
);
```

SearchService (snippet):

```typescript
search(searchForm: SearchForm): Observable<any> {
  const returnArray = [];

  if (searchForm.searchClients) {
    const searchClientParams = new Search();
    searchClientParams.searchPhrase = searchForm.searchPhrase;
    searchClientParams.type = SearchType.Client;
    const searchClients = this.objectSearch(searchClientParams);
    returnArray.push(searchClients);
  }

  if (searchForm.searchContacts) {
    const searchContactParams = new Search();
    searchContactParams.searchPhrase = searchForm.searchPhrase;
    searchContactParams.type = SearchType.Contact;
    const searchContacts = this.objectSearch(searchContactParams);
    returnArray.push(searchContacts);
  }

  return Observable.forkJoin(returnArray);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `return Observable.of(returnArray);` be sufficient?

Comment: Well AFAIK, in this example, of() would return an array of observables.  I want items from the observables to be emitted and as objects, not an array of objects..

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it correctly `returnArray` contains two Observables and you want to wait until they both complete but still you want to emit each result separately.

Since `forkJoin` emits all results in a array you could just unwrap it with `mergeMap` (or `concatMap`):

```typescript
this.searchService.search(action.payload)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(results => results),
    map((data) => new SearchSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => of(new SearchFail(error))),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped me get the answer - was being daft!  The mergeMap in the effect was what I was missing and changing the forkJoin to a concat helped me get simultaneous requests and response actions.  forkJoin waits until all observables complete

Comment: That's actually not exactly the same. With `forkJoin` all responses will be emitted when `forkJoin` completes. If you use `mergeMap` responses are emitted as they arrive so I don't know what behavior you prefer.

Comment: Thought the question was pretty clear tbh, but happy to update it...  I need the requests to be made at the same time and processed as and when they return; so not upon all completed like forkJoin